# How can I show first station which in this case is 1?

Tags: python, while-loop, continue

Right now the train is at the first Station, it will stop each station except when it reaches 3rd station, it won't stop there. we will say bye when we reach at the last station.

I have solved this except I failed to display the first station in the same statement with print.

```
current_station = 1
skip_station = 3
end_station = 7

# true if train isn't at the end station
while current_station < end_station:
    current_station = current_station + 1
    # if train reached  station # 3, skip that station
    if current_station == skip_station:
        continue
    else:
        print(current_station)
print('bye')
```

Comment: Easy solution: put another print before the loop.

Comment: tip: you can use `current_station += 1` as it means the same as `current_station = current_station + 1`

Answer (score 0):

```
current_station = 1
skip_station = 3
end_station = 7

# true if train isn't at the end station
while current_station < end_station:
    leaving_station = current_station
    current_station = current_station + 1
    # if train reached  station # 3, skip that station
    if current_station == skip_station:        
        continue
    else:
        print(leaving_station)
print('bye')
```

**Upd:** assuming we're considering offline algorithms only:

```py
current_station = 1
skip_station = 3
end_station = 7

for station in range(current_station, end_station):
    if station != skip_station:
        print(station)


print("Bye")
```

Or some hackish singleline:

```py
from collections import deque

current_station = 1
skip_station = 3
end_station = 7


deque(map(print, (i for i in range(current_station, end_station) if i != skip_station)), maxlen=0)
print("bye")
```

For all examples I assumed that `end_station` is *not* visited by train. Otherwise just add 1 to it.

Comment: the only edit is instead of next_station, it should be leaving_station

Comment: Well, code format in comments doesn't work as expected, i but hard to pars your comment. I just tried to apply minimal modifications to your code to make it do what you want. I'll update my answer with another version..

Comment: Oopsy.. fixed :-)

Comment: @greybeard, thanks! I'm sorry I haven't laptop with me yesterday. Just wanted to show some ideas. Now I have fixed, and all examples are runnable!

Answer (score 0):

```
current_station = 1
skip_station = 3
end_station = 7
# Because now the train will be leaving
if current_station==1:
    print(f'Train left from station: {current_station}')
# true if train isn't at the end station
while current_station < end_station:
    current_station = current_station + 1
    # if train reached  station # 3, skip that station
    if current_station == skip_station:
        continue
    else:
        print(f"The Train is at station: {current_station}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using while

```
print(current_station)
while current_station < end_station:
    current_station += 1
    if current_station == skip_station:
        continue
    print(current_station)
print('bye')
```

Using for-loop

```
for i in range(current_station,end_station):
    if i == skip_station:
        continue
    print(current_station)
print('bye')
```

Comment: Hi @sittsering, thanks for sharing. Your code works but I wanted to apply continue statement as I am learning that.

Comment: @SandraRay   oh, if that's the case, you can put one print before the loop as others suggested.

Comment: While both your original code and the revision using `continue` solve the problem with minimal ado: can you comment on repeating the `print()` call? What about `for … in range(current_station, …)`?

Comment: @greybeard You can do with for-loop as well, since op has used while-loop, I used it as well for solving it.

Comment: @greybeard I've removed `else` now, it wasn't needed.

Comment: The question about `for … in range()` is: is this cheating, or not?

Comment: only if you were asked to used while-loop. otherwise, nope.